# 'gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found' when trying to install Signal on freshly-installed Debian 10

Tags: debian, gpg, signal-messenger

I got the error why running `curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -`. This is my first time using Debian so there might be some config I have to do first.